# What is the best way to share some personal test code between repositories by CocoaPods podspec dependency?

Tags: git, dependencies, repository, cocoapods

I have two repositories for my personal test on Objective-C.(Pod_A & Pod_B)

There are some malloc functions at those repositories, so I create the other repository to put those same functions.(Pod_C)

then setting Pod_A.podspec

```
s.dependency 'Pod_C', :git => 'https://github.com/myName/Pod_C.git'
```

I pod install Pod_A fail,
then I find some issues on podspec dependency.
It seems to Unsupported dependency

```
s.dependency :git
```

[How do I create a CocoaPods podspec that has a dependency that exists outside of Specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447062/how-do-i-create-a-cocoapods-podspec-that-has-a-dependency-that-exists-outside-of)
[Is there a way to specify a dependency on another branch when building my Cocoapod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618936/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-dependency-on-another-branch-when-building-my-cocoap)